# Reading MSB and LSB if data is left-justified

Tags: c, embedded, bit-shift

While going through my coursework, I came across a function that reads temperature from the [TMP102 sensor](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf) (only required to measure positive temperatures).
The function first reads the MSB and LSB using I2C. Since the temperature data is **12-bit and left-justified**, the function proceeds as follows:

```
temp = ( (MSB << 8) | LSB) >> 4
```

I do not understand why this is done. Could someone please help me explain how the above line of code is related to the data being 12-bit and left-justified?

Comment: I suggest you write out some example values in binary on paper, then do the operations *on paper* and see what results you get.

Comment: note this assumes that the variable temp is unsigned and/or if signed that the compiler does not sign extend (and/or the msbit is never set).  otherwise it may mess up the result.

Comment: I would generally avoid the final right shift. The point of left-justification is to make the system largely independent of the actual ADC resolution.  If say you had a 10 bit sensor or a 16 bit sensor, the _magnitude_ would be the same, so any signal processing  code could be the same - you treat it all as if it were a 16 bit sensor.  If you shift-right by 4 you loose that _sample resolution independence_ and will have to modify the code for each different sensor you use.

Comment: @old_timer :  I guess for the bandwidth of an I2C  temperature sensor it is not critical from a performance point of view, for high speed DSP however it is just an unnecessary _per_sample_ operation.  I am not saying it is wrong; just that it is that way because it has distinct advantages and few disadvantages, and it should be considered.

Comment: I agree the extra shift is not required if the lower bits are known to be fixed, ideally zero.  And depending on architecture a mask might be cheaper than the shift if those bits are not fixed nor zero.  Depending on the i2c master if any or code that bit bangs none of this may be required, the two bytes might be able to be accumulated by the shifter and you are done there is your value...

Comment: Was simply trying extra support for your comment, guess I failed...

Comment: Rereading this doc (I have used this sensor in the past) the msbyte is first the lsbyte so depending on how the i2c logic/software works none of this may be required, this sensor is also one of those that it is either a 12 bit or 13 bit with zero padding (well maybe the zero bit is set).  Also as pointed out in the documentation you could just read the msbyte and use it, you lose some precision but as pointed out above you can simply adjust your scaling to deal with the weight of each bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `v` be a bit of the temperature value and `p` be a padding bit on the right, then you have

```
MSB = vvvvvvvv
LSB = vvvvpppp

---

  MSB << 8               = vvvvvvvv 00000000
 (MSB << 8) | LSB        = vvvvvvvv vvvvpppp
((MSB << 8) | LSB) >> 4  = 0000vvvv vvvvvvvv
```

In the last line, you see the correct representation as a 16bit value (with the upper 4 bits always `0`).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation. But is this not right-aligned? i see the `v` temperature bits are aligned to the right in the final result.

Comment: @Jspake the values you get from the sensor are left-aligned. Of course you need "right aligned" in the end, this is how integer representation works, the least significant bit is the one all to the right.

Comment: @Jspake: As Felix said, the sensor data are left-aligned: `vvvvvvvv vvvvpppp` and the result has to be right-aligned for sure.

Comment: Aah yes, the data needs to go back to being right-aligned. Thanks!

Comment: How would we make that portable and working for signed integer as well? Right shift is implementation defined.